# How to make data fetching work together with Redux Toolkit and React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying the examples in the Redux Toolkit docs:

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-sound-1ybmf?file=/features/counter/Counter.js

and it works.

And then I tried to do [the following also in the docs just to fetch some data and display on the page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide), using

```js
const fetchUsers = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(usersLoading());
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  dispatch(usersReceived(data));
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-northcutt-lb4ww?file=/features/users/Users.js

But it'd error with `No reducer provided for key "users"` and `Store does not have a valid reducer.`

How can it be made to work?  And the function `fetchUsers()`, does it belong to `Users.js` or `usersSlice.js`, and are there other things that needs to be changed in this data fetching mechanism using Redux Toolkit?

Comment: Just use react-query, don't bother using global client state management to work with server state.https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview

Comment: @Domino987 does react-query provide a "one and only data store" like Redux? But suppose the project need to work with Redux or the team has decided to use React and Redux or Redux Toolkit?

Comment: Even better, everything is cached and synced between components. Yes thats why I am looking at your code tight now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the export of the user actions to the user slice but you are still importing the userSlice reducer at a whole to create your store.

```
export const { usersLoading, usersReceived } = usersSlice.actions
```

Since you are not exporting the slice, it fails to access the slice. You need to additionally export the slice with `export default usersSlice.reducer`, so that `import usersReducer from "../features/users/usersSlice";`  works again